# Can I look for broken resources on my homepage with Codeception?

Tags: php, integration-testing, codeception

I want to make sure none of my scripts / CSS / images are failing. Is there something like this?

```
$I->wantTo('Verify all resources are loading');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->seeFailingResourceCountIs(0);
```

Something that would fail if an image can't be loaded, or causes a server error, etc.

Comment: I really like this idea, have you put it as a feature request on Codeception's github? https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues

Comment: Nope, In fact, I found there was no easy place to see all of the commands at my disposal, so I didn't have a way to find out if it already existed or not. If you're saying it doesn't exist, then yeah let's make it a feature request (or please feel free to make it and cc me, i'm bobbydavid@ there)

Comment: You're not wrong, the documentation is pretty sketchy. The best I've found is an aptly named "switch to iframe" page that contains all the documentation for WebDriver: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver